# maintaining the order of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, relationship

lets say I have 1 vector of names and another vector for the telephone numbers. First, the user will enter names (not sorted, meaning they are not organized from a to z), then, the user will enter the corresponding telephone number.

After filling out both vectors, the program then executes sorting mechanism in the name vector(vector 1). The problem is now the vector 2, (since  there is no adopting mechanism to map it to vector 1).

Example:

```
vector name  |  vector telephone
f               232132
a               34242342
b               997345

the result will be

vector name  |  vector telephone
a               232132
b               34242342
f               997345
```

as you can see, the vector telephone hasnt been adjusted. how can we adjust this?? thanks

Comment: Why don't you just make things simpler and have a vector of objects each of which hold both a name and the number?

Comment: Or map names to numbers.

Comment: A map would be a waste of resources.

Comment: any sample implementation for mapping names to numbers?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley is that possible?

Comment: @user963499: `struct { string name; int number; };`

Comment: BL, the code is an error, you haven't defined a name for the struct. He could use a pair<string, int> from the STL if he's using vectors.

Comment: @JustinDanielson: Meh. Pretend it's there.

Comment: If he has an aversion to creating objects, that error could cause more frustration. I up voted it though. He should be able to put it together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a struct that holds a string for the name and a string/int for the phone number. Go through it linearly and record the name information. Go through it again and record the phone # information. Then sort.

If you do not wish to create a class, you can use a [pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/) object.

```
vector<pair<string,int> > nameAndNumber;
```

Edit: fixed a bug, thanks smocking

Comment: is it possible to use only vectors (mapping 2 vectors), without using a struct or class?

Comment: If you write your own sorting function, you could have it change both vectors at the same time as it sorts the names vectors. But the best thing to do is to create a class or struct that will hold the information within the same object.

Comment: OP didn't specify C++11, so might want to change that to `vector<pair<string,int> > nameAndNumber;` to avoid invoking the right shift operator.

Answer (score 1):

> the vector telephone hasnt been adjusted. how can we adjust this??

By combining both entities "name" and "telephone" inside a data structure and then use its `vector`.

```
struct NameNumber {
  std::string t_Name;
  unsigned long t_Number;

  bool operator < (const NameNumber&) const;  // use 't_Name' inside
};
std::vector<NameNumber> v;
```

For completeness of the solution, I have mentioned the `operator <` which will sort the `vector` according to the names.